# My for loop is only going through once

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I wrote this code here. It is supposed to print out the `iteNum.length` (array) which is determined by the user input, but it only does one iteration and then it stops. I can't figure out why.

```
for (int i = 0; i < iteNum.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("Num:" + (i+1) + " ");

    for (i = 0; i < cMiles.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" (sc" + (i+1) +  ":)" + cRandom[i] + " (tsc" + (i+1) + ":)" + df.format(cTimes[i]) + " ");
    }                 

    for (i = 0; i < fMiles.length; i++){
        System.out.print(" (sf"+ (i+1) +  ":)" + df.format(fRandom[i]) + " (tsf" + (i+1) + ":)" + df.format(fTimes[i])+ " " );
    }

    System.out.print("(cT:)" + df.format(cSum) + " (fT:)" + df.format(fSum));

    if (cSum < fSum) {
        System.out.print(" City is faster");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print(" Freeway is faster");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're reusing the same `i` variable in the inner and outer loops. Use separate variables.

```
for (int i = 0; i < iteNum.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cMiles.length; j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As say @John you are using same iterator variable `i`, instread of using another one

And also this code can be simplified

```
if (cSum < fSum) {
    System.out.print(" City is faster");
}
else {
    System.out.print(" Freeway is faster");
}
```

like that

```
System.out.print((cSum < fSum) ? " City is faster" : " Freeway is faster");
```

On my opinion ternary operator more clear.

Comment: Unfortunately this makes more sense but our instructor wants us to utilize a if else statement for this portion.